# Setting setOnKeyListener for a ListView

Tags: android

I have been trying to set an `OnKeyListener`, but I am not sure how I can get the selected row on the `ListView` in the `View.OnKeyListener`.  The `v` parameter always gives me the `ListView`, not the selected row.  Any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
listView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //....
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you call the getCheckedItemPosition on your list view to determine this?

public int getCheckedItemPosition ()
Since: API Level 1

Returns the currently checked item. The result is only valid if the choice mode has been set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE.
Returns

    * The position of the currently checked item or INVALID_POSITION if nothing is selected

See Also

    * setChoiceMode(int)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [AbsListView.getSelectedView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getSelectedView%28%29) method:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) v;
    if (listView.getSelectedView() != null) {
        // (cast if necessary) and use selected view
    }
}
```

If you interested in selected item position, id or associated object  you can use [AdapterView.getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()), [AdapterView.getSelectedItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemId()) and [AdapterView.getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()) methods correspondingly.

Comment: What can be a problem if `getSelectedView()` always returns null, even if I put `setSelection(index)` right above it?